# ncurses-devel problems in SuSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, suse, ncurses, yast

Searching on the WEB, I found [this tutorial](https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/compiling-de-linux-kernel-suse-way/) (the only one that has convinced me) for installing a new kernel and I followed the steps provided.

But, I got these problems:

In the first step I tried to install the `ncurses-devel` via terminal using the `zypper` and the YaST Software Management, but in the first case I got this error:

```
No provider of 'ncurses-devel' found.
```

Using the YaST, I didn't find the source of the package listed.

Then, I downloaded the application from the [WEB site](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/#downloads) and I got the following error:

Executing the `make` command

```
/bin/sh: -I../c++: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [../objects/cursesf.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nat64/Desktop/SW/ncurses-5.9/c++'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

In the same way, when I execute the `make install`, the terminal showed me the same errors.

Finally, I wrote in the terminal `yast -i ncurses-devel`, without success. It marked me that the source was not found.

I need to install 7 kernels for the project that I'm doing in my virtual machine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with YaST, but `ncurses-devel` is a pretty fundamental package as far as devel packages go -- if your package manager says it can't be found, there is something wrong with the way YaST is configured, or the system's internet access.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here:

1. If `zypper in ncurses-devel` fails, something is wrong with your system - do you have **any** repositories enabled at all? What SUSE based distribution are you using?
2. To compile the kernel you don't need ncurses at all (it would be a pretty silly requirement for such a low-lewel piece of software). You need ncurses (and its devel package) to build TUI kernel configuration tools like `nconfig` or `menuconfig` (invoked via `make menuconfig` or `make nconfig`), the kernel as such does not have any such dependency. That said, if you are unable to install the ncurses devel package, use `make oldconfig` - it uses plain text interface, without any additional requirements.

Comment: How can I check the repositories installed on the OS? My SuSE distribution is: SuSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11 SP3

Comment: `zypper lr` (for list repositories), or yoy can use `yast`.