# Trouble compiling ncurses 5 on SLES 2011

Tags: compiling, suse, sles, ncurses

To my chagrin, I am working as a non-root user on an SLES (SUSE Linux Enterprise) 11. I'm not root and cannot have packages installed.

I'm trying  to build ncurses-5.9. The build configures and make advances pretty far with no hitches, but then at some point I get

```
cd ../objects;   -I../c++ -I../include -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -I. -I../include -I/opt/nano/include/ncurses  -c ../c++/cursesf.cc
/bin/sh: -I../c++: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [../objects/cursesf.o] Error 127
```

It seems like Make is using some variable for a binary that doesn't exist.

This problem is similar to the one described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/141606/34868), but unlike in that question - I can't install the distribution's packaged version; nor am I trying to build the distro's version. I've downloaded the tarball from the ncurses website.

How can I get the build to complete?

Answer (score 2):

It's an FAQ: [*Do I need the C++ binding?*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#config_cplus)

> With 5.0, the configure script provides two options (***`--without-cxx`*** and ***`--without-cxx-binding`***). Use the former to suppress the configure checks for the C++ compiler, e.g., when there is no working C++ compiler on your system. Use the latter to omit the C++ binding, if you must.

The problem itself should be apparent:

```
cd ../objects;   -I../c++ 
              ^^^ (no C++ compiler was found)
```

Comment: 1. That's not what I asked 2. My system _does_ have a C++ compiler, which works fine. 3. I've already noted we can work around the problem by using `--without-cxx`, in my answer.

Comment: 5.9's old, but the configure check in that area hasn't changed for quite a while.  The error you're commenting on happens when it doesn't find a C++ compiler.  If you're able to reproduce the problem with a current release of ncurses, that's something to report on `bug-ncurses@gnu.org`

Answer (score 0):

A workaround - which should be good enough - is to configure ncurses not to try and build the C++-related parts:

```
./configure --without-cxx
```

so the folder which triggers the problem gets skipped.